# Stimulsoft Pdf Report dynamic unicode strings

Tags: c#, pdf, unicode, report, stimulsoft

i have a report file which is in Persian language, and i generate it using bellow code:

```
StiReport report = new StiReport();
        var stream = new MemoryStream();
        var setting = new StiPdfExportSettings
        {
            ImageQuality = 1.0f,
            ImageResolution = 300,
            EmbeddedFonts = false,
            UseUnicode = true,
            StandardPdfFonts = true
        };
        report.Load(Server.MapPath(reportUrl));
        report.RegData("factorReport", model);
        report.RegData("factorReport_userBillDetails", model.UserBillDetail);
        report.Render();
        report.ExportDocument(StiExportFormat.Pdf, stream, setting);
        byte[] bytesInStream = stream.ToArray();
        stream.Close();
        Response.Clear();
        Response.ContentType = "application/force-download";
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;    filename=Factor" + model.factorId + ".pdf");
        Response.BinaryWrite(bytesInStream);
        Response.End();
        return View();
```

the report gets generated with no problem on development machine
[image: Report on development machine]

but when published to production server as you see [image: Report on Production Server] the dynamic part becomes problem, at first i thought may be the problem is with font but as you see in the picture all labels are using the same font, but only the dynamic part is in squares. after that i changed it to Tahoma font which is a universal font and supports Persian, suddenly the squares changed to question marks!!!!!

i already created fiz files and loaded to font info table of Stimulsoft, any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: Your development machine is an IIS Express? And what is settings of your production sever? Also does `Response` has a property for setting encoding? If yes, try to set it as UTF-8 or similar.

Comment: yes the development runs with express and production runs on top of full version of IIS, but about response encoding, the both use the same code so if one needs encoding the other must need it to, and apart from that encodings are partially incorrect not fully

Comment: Development machine and server can contain different versions of font files, so please try to set  (1) EmbeddedFonts=true, UseUnicode=true,
 or (2) EmbeddedFonts=false, UseUnicode=false, StandardPdfFonts=false

Answer (score 2):

This is late to answer this question but for whom maybe find this later.

The problem is about using non standard Persian fonts, fonts like Mitra, Nazanin, Yekan and others is not standard and in situations that we mix Persian and Latin characters or sometimes when using numbers, will show squares in PDF export.

To solve this problem use Persian standard fonts like IranSANS and so on.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this snippet to include your desired font:

```
Stimulsoft.Base.StiFontCollection.AddFontFile(Server.MapPath("<Path To Font>"));
// should be used before Building report
StiReport report = new StiReport();
```

For example:

```
Stimulsoft.Base.StiFontCollection.AddFontFile(Server.MapPath("~//fonts//Byekan.ttf"));
```

Also, use this before exporting:

```
StiExportSettings exportSettings = new StiPdfExportSettings();
((StiPdfExportSettings)exportSettings).EmbeddedFonts = true;
((StiPdfExportSettings)exportSettings).UseUnicode = true;
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
report.ExportDocument(StiExportFormat.Pdf, stream, exportSettings);
```